# running a docker container with systemd

Tags: docker, systemd

I have a service definition that starts a docker container using systemd on CentOS 7:

```
[Unit]
Description=MappingService
After=portal.service
Requires=docker.service

[Service]
TimeoutStartSec=3000
Type=forking
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/Downloads/MS_0.3.4_artifact
ExecStartPre=-/bin/docker rm -f eb-mapping-service-container
ExecStartPre=/home/user/Downloads/MS_0.3.4_artifact/deploy.sh /home/user/Downloads/MS_0.3.4_artifact/eb-mapping-service.tgz
ExecStartPre=/bin/docker run -v /dev/log:/dev/log -d -ti --log-driver=journald --network=bridge -p 9090:9090 --name eb-mapping-service-container eb-mapping-service  /bin/bash -c "cd /build/MappingService; ./start_multiple_clients_mapping_service.sh"
ExecStart=/bin/docker start -a eb-mapping-service-container
ExecStop=/bin/docker stop eb-mapping-service-container

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This service works. The Docker container it launches is up.
Whenever I boot the computer it is running. My problem with this service is that it's never reaching the Active(Running) status. Instead, it is stuck in 'Activating(start)' status.
The 'start_multiple_clients_mapping_service.sh' script starts a node.js server and it starts listening, so it isn't exiting directly.

I've searched everywhere and scoured Docker's documentation about this and couldn't find an answer.

Also, if I remove the '-a' from the docker start command, then the status will be Inactive(dead) even though the container will be up and running.
Update:
After a while, I don't have an exact number, the service fails with the timeout reason. This isn't after 3000 seconds but way earlier. **Although the service failed, the docker is still on the air and can be used**.
I've verified with `docker container ls`

**Question:

How do I change my service definition to reflect the Active(Running) status for the docker?**

Comment: The problem is that your service is not actually _forking_, as you specified in `Type=`. The container process is not a child of the `docker start` process, it is a child of docker daemon, which runs separately (_more formally there is a longer hierarchy, but the main point is that it is not related to `docker start` process_). Because you classified your service as `forking`, `systemd` waits for `docker start` to spawn the child process and exit, leaving the child running, but instead `docker start` keeps running  (because of `-a` option), so `systemd` thinks that the service is starting up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I understood the problem. There were a couple of things wrong:

1. the docker run command should not be used with the flags -d and -ti.
2. the Type should be set to exec instead of forking.

After doing these two changes, I got the much sought after Active(Running) status with the Docker successfully launched.